# How can I use ODE45 to solve coupled differential equations dependent on frequency?

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, ode45

[Equation 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4Vu9.png)

[Equation 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnw8F.png)

`FREQ = 1:1000;
P = 1i * (2 * pi * FREQ);`

[Constant Values & State Variable Equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OJjU.png)

For this particular problem, the forcing function P is frequency dependent. It will be moving the masses. How can I implement ODE45 to solve the equations with frequency being the conditions that change? (Disregard the value of P in the image 3.)

Comment: The whole is still a time dependent dynamic? What is `F`? A constant, an oscillation, some periodic function composed of several sinusoids? Do you want to compare the behavior for different forcing frequencies? Please clarify.

Comment: F = P = 1i * (2 * pi * FREQ) I want to solve the state variable equations for each case of F (P)  from 1 to 1000 Hz, and plot the velocities vs Freq at the end.

Comment: But that is not a frequency, there is no periodic process involved. This is just a constant, and then imaginary, force that will shift the position values somewhat into a non-physical area.

Comment: This is a term for forced vibration of a system. When solved, it's supposed to show the resonant frequency response of the system.

Comment: So you want $F(t)=A*cos(P*t)$ and you want to construct something like a frequency response graph?

Comment: Right. I'd be satisfied with a symbolic solution of the equations if that were possible. I've seen the coupled equations solved by Ax = b, so I don't know if that'll work here.

Comment: But you can solve everything symbolically. The equations are linear, thus apply Fourier or Laplace transform (whatever you prefer) to get the frequency response behavior. This then is linear algebra in 2 unknowns. Ask on math.stackexchange.com for specific questions about this symbolic solution.